# Javascript wont run on jQuery Mobile until after refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, jquery-mobile

I know that there are multiple threads on here already discussing this issue, but none of the suggestions posted so far have led me to a solution. So, I shall post my own. Basically I have a javascript function that is set to run on one of my pages. It doesn't work until after the page is refreshed. My understanding is that the issue has something to do with the way that ajax loads the page?

Things I have tried:

- Adding the script code to the layout of front page that the user sees first
- When that didnt work, adding the script code to all 3 of the layout's the site uses
- Adding the script to the body of this particular layout.

The code is below. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

**This is the code for the layout:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title>RENT</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "my.css" %>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "my.js" %>
        <script src="/assets/jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- THIS IS THE FUNCTION I NEED HELP WITH! -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#paymentAmount").maskMoney({symbol:'$ '});
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page4">
          <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
              <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="/home"
               data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                  Back
              </a>
              <a id="settings" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"
               href="#page9" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">
              </a>
              <h3>
                  Pay Rent
              </h3>
          </div>

        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:error], :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:notice], :id => "flash_notice") if flash[:notice] %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:alert], :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>

        <%= yield %>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
              <h1>
                  © 2013
              </h1>
          </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the code for the controller:**

```
<!-- Pay Rent (R) -->
  <div data-role="content" style="padding: 10px">
    <%= form_for(@rentPayment, :url => { action: "create" }) do |f| %>z
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
        <label for="paymentAmount"> Payment Amount </label>
        <input name="rentPayment[paymentAmount]" id="paymentAmount" placeholder="$ 0.00" value="" type="text">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
        <label for="paymentDate"> Pay on this date </label>
        <input name="rentPayment[paymentDate]" id="paymentDate" placeholder="" value="" type="date">
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" data-theme="b" value="Submit Payment" data-mini="true">
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**Edited layout page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title>RENT</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "my.css" %>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "my.js" %>
        <script src="/assets/jquery.maskMoney.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- THIS IS THE FUNCTION I NEED HELP WITH! -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#page4', function () { $("#paymentAmount").maskMoney({symbol:'$ '}); });
    <!--$(document).ready(function(){$("#paymentAmount").maskMoney({symbol:'$ '});})-->
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page4">
          <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
              <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" href="/home"
               data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                  Back
              </a>
              <a id="settings" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"
               href="#page9" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">
              </a>
              <h3>
                  Pay Rent
              </h3>
          </div>

        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:error], :id => "flash_error") if flash[:error] %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:notice], :id => "flash_notice") if flash[:notice] %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, flash[:alert], :id => "flash_alert") if flash[:alert] %>

        <%= yield %>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
              <h1>
                  © 2013
              </h1>
          </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready(function(){...});` ?

Comment: Try `$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageID', function () { $("#paymentAmount").maskMoney({symbol:'$ '}); });`

Comment: @Omar Which page am I putting this on? The layout for this particular page or the layout for the home page or both?

Comment: For the particular page.

Comment: @Omar It didn't work.

Comment: Could you please post the code you've added?

Comment: @Omar: Done. It is above. Also, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: `<!-- comments HTML -->` use `// for code` ;) try again :)

Comment: -_- *facepalm*. I tried just deleting the line though, and it still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28066/discussion-between-omar-and-zack)